# Case-insensitive Bob Jenkins Hash?

Tags: delphi, hash, delphi-2010

Is there a case-insensitive variant of the Bob Jenkins hash function?

```
Generics.Defaults.BobJenkinsHash
```

provides a fast hash function. Unfortunately it cannot be used in combination with a case-insensitive compare function like so

```
TCustomStringComparer = class (TEqualityComparer <String>)
  function Equals(const Left, Right: String): Boolean; override;
  function GetHashCode(const Value: String): Integer; override;
end;
function TCustomStringComparer.Equals (const Left, Right : String) : Boolean;
begin
  Result := CompareText (Left, Right) = 0;
end;
function TCustomStringComparer.GetHashCode (const Value : String) : Integer;
begin
  Result := Generics.Defaults.BobJenkinsHash (Value [1], Length (Value) * SizeOf (Char), 0);
end;
```

This is because TDictionary first compares the hash codes and then uses the provided comparer when checking for equality.

Of course I could use UpperCase in my `GetHashCode` function, but I wondered if it would be faster if I could somehow modify the hash function itself.

Comment: For Delphi 2010 the use of `CompareText()` and `UpperCase()` is wrong - these functions won't do for Unicode strings. See for example https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=26949&tstart=0.

Comment: CompareText() and UpperCase() are also wrong for AnsiStrings because they only operate on ASCII strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no case invariant version of the hash function. Lower or upper case all strings before passing them to the hash function.

Comment: Yes, and I am confirming it as an solution.

Answer (score 5):

It would be slightly faster, but it hurts your maintainability a lot. There is rarely a good reason for this type of micro-optimization. Just convert your strings to lower or upper case before hashing like you suggested.

> "We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the
>   time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil. Yet we should not
>   pass up our opportunities in that
>   critical 3%. A good programmer will
>   not be lulled into complacency by such
>   reasoning, he will be wise to look
>   carefully at the critical code; but
>   only after that code has been
>   identified" - Donald Knuth

Comment: +1 for Knuth's FULL quote. So often we only get the "premature optimization is the root of all evil" part.

Comment: The Knuth quote is good, but you should have taken it to heart yourself, especially the "after that code has been identified" part - what makes you say it would be slightly faster? I don't think so. And both our opinions are essentially worthless without profiling the code.

Answer (score 3):

IMO the whole question is wrong. To quote the [Wikipedia article on hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_funct):

> A **hash function** is any well-defined procedure or mathematical function which converts a large, possibly variable-sized amount of data into a small datum, usually a single integer that may serve as an index to an array.

Note the "amount of data" - there is no type specified, and indeed the Bob Jenkins hash function has an untyped parameter `const Data` pointing to the data to be hashed. Since the input data is not necessarily a sequence of characters there is no way to compute a "case-insensitive" hash value. And even if it were a sequence of characters - the upper- or lowercasing would depend on character set and encoding. So you would need to have different hash functions for ASCII strings, UTF-8 encoded strings, UTF-16 LE encoded strings, ... (you get the idea).

Comment: hmm...that seems right...okay then, i will go for the upperCase then...or the unicode version of that

Answer (score 0):

I also needed such a function in a project. Bob Jenkin's one-at-a-time hash:

```
function hash(const s: string): cardinal;
var
  p, last: PByte;
begin
  if s = '' then exit(1);
  p := pbyte(pointer(s));
  last := p + length(s);
  result := 0;
  while p < last do begin
    if {$ifdef asciionly}p^ < 128{$else}true{$endif}  then begin
      result := result + p^;
      if (p^ >= ord('a')) and (p^ <= ord('z')) then result := result - ord('a') + ord('A');
      result := result + (result shl 10);
      result := result xor (result shr 6);
    end;
    inc(p);
  end;

  result := result + (result shl 3);
  result := result xor (result shr 11);
  result := result + (result shl 15);
end;
```

If asciionly is set, it should also give the same hash for utf-8 and latin1 strings.

Do not forget to disable overflow checking.